# Is the Massiah a human adopted by G-d?

Tags: messiah, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Is the Mashiach a human adopted by G-d?

> Behold My servant, I will support him, My chosen one, whom My soul desires; I have placed My spirit upon him, he shall promulgate justice to the nations.

([Yeshayah 42:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.42.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by adopted?

Comment: you are quoting, by the way, from a messianic Christian bible https://www.biblegateway.com/versions/Orthodox-Jewish-Bible-OJB/

Comment: If you sre going to try to show a translation, do not transliterate. Here is a Jewish translation https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15973/showrashi/true

Comment: Updated question with Jewish source.

Answer (score 0):

[Yeshayahu 42:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15973/showrashi/true)

> הֵ֚ן עַבְדִּי֙ אֶתְמָךְ־בּ֔וֹ בְּחִירִ֖י רָֽצְתָ֣ה נַפְשִׁ֑י נָתַ֚תִּי רוּחִי֙ עָלָ֔יו מִשְׁפָּ֖ט לַגּוֹיִ֥ם יוֹצִֽיא:

> Behold My servant, I will support him, My chosen one, whom My soul
> desires; I have placed My spirit upon him, he shall promulgate justice
> to the nations.

If you are going to try a translation use a valid Jewish translation. Since Yeshayahu is referring to the Children of Israel here in this chapter, the sentence does indeed mean that he is a  human being like any other human beings.

Rashi explains:

> **Behold My servant, I will support him:** Behold My servant Jacob is not like you, for I will support him.
> **My chosen one:** Israel is called ‘My chosen one’ ([mss.:] His chosen one) (Ps. 135:4) “For the Eternal chose Jacob for Himself.”
> Scripture states also (infra 45:4): “For the sake of My servant Jacob
> and Israel My chosen one.”
> **whom My soul desires; I have placed My spirit upon him:** to let his prophets know My secret, and his end will be that ‘he shall promulgate
> justice to the nations,’ as it is stated (supra 2:3): “And let Him
> teach us of His ways etc.”

Comment: "it does indeed mean as human beings like any other human beings" that isn't a comprehensible sentence.

Comment: @robev I rewrote the sentence to be more understandable

Answer (score -2):

To answer your question, yes, the Messiah will be human, and like other humans, he, too, will die like all humans. I do not comprehend the meaning of G-d adopting a messiah. What does that mean?